# Alignment of structure members for heap allocated variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a structure where the members have certain alignment requirements while no such requirement exist for the structure itself.

I'm using gcc so using __attribute__((aligned(n))) will do the trick, unless (as far as I know) an instance of the struct is allocated on the heap.

How do I keep the alignment for heap allocated instances? posix_memalign(3) will align the structure itself, but not the structure members, so I can't see how to make it work with that function.

The source is here: https://github.com/colding/disruptorC/blob/master/src/disruptor.h#L92

Comment: If the structure is properly aligned, the members will be as well.

Comment: If you align the structure to the maximum of the members' alignments, it should be fine, non?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter where a struct is—stack or heap—the layout of the struct must be the same. The compiler ensures that the `sizeof()` and the layout of elements within the struct match the alignment requirements (via padding). It also gives the struct itself a required alignment so that its members end up on the right boundary (this value is the largest alignment of any of its members).

So just use `posix_memalign` and you'll be fine:

```
MyStruct* ptr;
posix_memalign(&ptr, alignof(MyStruct), sizeof(MyStruct));
```

For example, if you have this definition:

```
struct MyStruct {
    char c;
    double d;
}
```

It's compiler-dependent, of course, but the most likely behavior is that the compiler lays out the following:

- 1-byte char
- 7 bytes of padding
- 8-byte double

and gives the whole thing an alignment of 8 bytes. Then, if the struct itself is aligned properly (on an 8-byte boundary), the double that's 8 bytes offset into it will also be properly aligned.

(`alignof` is different in different compilers/standards: `__alignof__` in gcc, `__alignof` in MSVC, and `alignof` in C11/C++11.)

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to make sure that the individual members are aligned on at least cache line size offsets. So the natural alignment of, say, a double or a char, will not be enough to ensure that these members are aligned on cache line size offsets even though the structure itself is.

Comment: It applies to both alignment and natural alignment. If your member is declared with `__attribute__((aligned(n)))`, this applies.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought that the aligned attribute was completely ignored for instances on the heap. If that is not the case, then I have no problems. Thanks.

Comment: @colding The key is that the struct's layout is identical no matter where it is. So if the compiler worked some magic to make it aligned properly on the stack and you massage the starting address the same way it does, then it *has* to just work.